# Can Bintray sign packages/files using a signing subkey?

Tags: gnupg, bintray

**TL;DR**: Can [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) sign files or packages using a signing key which is a subkey, or is a master signing key (also?) required?

In my private keyring I (originally) have a master key (`[SC]`) with its standard encryption subkey (`[E]`).  To this I added a signing subkey (`[S]`) that I hope to use to sign software packages (uploaded to Bintray).  Later I remove the master key from my keyring for safe-keeping, retaining only the subkeys I need for signing and encryption.

I have two ASCII-armored exports of private keys:

- One was produced using `--export-secret-keys` and **contains the master key and two subkeys**;
- the other was produced using `--export-secret-subkeys` and **contains only the subkeys**, including the added signing subkey.

Attempting to sign packages uploaded to Bintray:

- If I supply Bintray with the **full private-key export containing the master key and subkeys**, Bintray signing operations (via the API) **work correctly**.  When I download the file and `.asc` signature, I can see that Bintray used the master key to sign.
- If I instead supply the smaller private key export containing **only the subkeys**, all signing operations fail with **405 Not Allowed**.

By supply of the private key here I mean either via the `private_key` parameter of the `api.bintray.com/gpg` API call, or pre-set in my account on Bintray as the private key.

Should I expect to be able to sign in Bintray using the signing subkey?  Of course I can create an armored/detached asc signature in my local shell using `gpg`, without the master key being in my keyring, using the signing subkey.  But can I do this in Bintray?